# jQuery Mobile listview paging

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What is the effective way to deal with long list in jQuery Mobile listview?
Take 1000 items for example, showing 1000 items all at once would effectively render it useless to user. Just imagine scrolling such a long list.

I'm thinking of implementing custom paging for listview, is there better approach other than rolling my own paging solution?

**UPDATE
Please check my updated answer with Fiddle example below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I've decided to make my own lazy-loading listview plugin.
And it turned out really great user-experience!

Just a tip for those still looking for solution of long scrolling list.

--UPDATE

I've to say sorry that I didn't have time to post an example earlier, as I'm not allowed to post the source code we used onto the Internet. 
Now that finally I'm free and decided to spent a few hours to rebuild the lazy-loading listview (freshly out of my head).

SCRIPT:

```
var per_page = 20; //max images per page
var page = 1; //initialize page number
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadFlckr(20, 1); //load some images onload
});

//Handler for scrolling toward end of document
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
        //End of page, load next content here
        if (!loading) loadNextPage();
    }
});

//Load content for next page
function loadNextPage() {
    loadFlckr(per_page, ++page);
}

//Load images from Datasource (Flickr in this case)
function loadFlckr(per_page, page) {
    loading = true; //interlock to prevent multiple calls
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&format=json&api_key=2fd4e1a42e243e332b7e334aa219698e&user_id=74038643@N00&jsoncallback=?";

    //Calling to service provider
    $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
        per_page: per_page || 20,
        page: page || 1
    })
        .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function (i, item) {
            var url = String.format("http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_{4}.jpg", item.farm, item.server, item.id, item.secret, 't');
            var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", url);
            var li = $("<li/>").append(img);
            var title = $("<h2/>").append(item.title || 'No Title');
            var desc = $("<p/>").append(item.owner);
            li.append(title);
            li.append(desc);
            //Append new list item to listview
            li.appendTo("#list-lazyloader");
        });
        //refresh listview
        $('#list-lazyloader').listview('refresh');
        loading = false;
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        //Update page index
        page = data.photos.page;
        //Update photos count
        $('#photoCount').text($('#list-lazyloader li').size());
    });
};

//C#-like feature to concat strings
String.format = function () {
    var s = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
        s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
     <h1>Photos (<span id="photoCount">0</span>)</h1>

</div>
<ul id="list-lazyloader" data-role="listview" data-theme="d"></ul>
```

And here's the working Fiddle:

[Lazy-loading Listview](http://jsfiddle.net/fF675/154/)

Have fun =)

Updated on 1/8/2017: fixed the broken Flickr API in case public still interest in this solution

Comment: Why is this down-voted? Is it wrong implementing lazy-loading myself?

Comment: It might help if you provide information on your own solution.

Comment: Very unhelpful answer

Comment: @MilkMiruku Sorry that my response comes late. I've updated my answer with a working fiddle now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution: https://github.com/stakbit/jQuery-Mobile-Listview-Pagination-Plugin (I am the developer of this plugin)

It's a simple jquery mobile listview pagination plugin that basically adds a "Show More" button to the end of a list (list item count and label text are configurable) and does an Ajax call each time the "Show More" button is clicked. Also works with the jquery mobile Search input box enabled and does caching as well.

Comment: This is open source software licensed under the MIT license. I linked to my plugin for others to benefit from. Download and use it if you want no pressure. Again, it's open source code that I put effort into developing and use in my own projects. I'm sure other's with the same requirements will find it useful. It is very relevant to this thread so why would I not mention it?

Comment: There's no problem with it being mentioned, but you should follow the guidelines in the FAQ referred to in my comment.  Specifically you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.  You did so in the other answer you posted, but not in this one.

Comment: Ok, I updated my post to specifically call out that I am the developer of this plugin - Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the idea.  I can't vouch for the linked plugin as I just needed something to kick-start my addled mind.  The "Show More" button is exactly what I need to do.  Thanks :)