# Jquery mobile search and pagination

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am using jQuery mobile for one web application, i am bit confused about the listing with pagination and search filter.

Could find anything after several hours of search on the internet.

Is there any plugin for this or do I need to do custom coding...?

Comment: _"search from couple hours on internet"_? That could not have been relevant searching. Took me 5 seconds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621871/jquery-mobile-listview-paging. On Google: "jquery mobile search pagination". **Update**: Another [**link**](https://github.com/stakbit/jQuery-Mobile-Listview-Pagination-Plugin) ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-mobile-pagination-plugin.html

About the search filter, i think you will have to first think the kind of filter you want to provide (i.e. text-boxes, drop down lists, radio buttons, etc.) You would have to design your filter and then just apply it to the query. I don't think you can just plug in a filter from somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Custom coding is recomended. Plugins you can find but only if you load everything when the page loads. ex: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/  or http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/